# I can't decode API link and get text from array

Tags: swift, decoding

```
import Foundation

struct Movies: Codable {
let page: Int
var results: \[Result\]

    let totalPages, totalResults: Int
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case page, results
        case totalPages = "total_pages"
        case totalResults = "total_results"
    }

}

struct Result: Codable {
let adult: Bool
let backdropPath: String
let genreIDS: \[Int\]
let id: Int
let originalLanguage: OriginalLanguage
let originalTitle, overview: String
let popularity: Double
let posterPath, releaseDate, title: String
let video: Bool
let voteAverage: Double
let voteCount: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case adult
        case backdropPath = "backdrop_path"
        case genreIDS = "genre_ids"
        case id
        case originalLanguage = "original_language"
        case originalTitle = "original_title"
        case overview, popularity
        case posterPath = "poster_path"
        case releaseDate = "release_date"
        case title, video
        case voteAverage = "vote_average"
        case voteCount = "vote_count"
    }

}

enum OriginalLanguage: String, Codable {
case en = "en"
case es = "es"
case it = "it"
}

class APIManager {

    var title1 = Result.CodingKeys.title.rawValue
    
    static let shared = APIManager()
    
    let urlString = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=d35da28c5f884f89607c3388f07c2f5e"
    
    func getMovie(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        let url = URL(string: urlString)!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data else {return}
            if let title = try? JSONDecoder().decode(title1.self, from: data) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    completion(title)
                } }
            else {
                print("FAIL")
            }
            
        }
                task.resume()
    }

}
```

So I need to get movie titles from this array and put them to another "struct". I've tried many options. Sometimes I got "FAIL", sometimes it works, but I don't get movie titles from API. I also put Movies or Result instead of "title1 and then tried tried to find way to "title" a get results. But I couldn't get anything because after decoding Result I got [Result] and Swift answered that [Result] doesn't contain title

Thank you in advance guys!

Comment: Replace `try?` with `try` in a proper `do/catch` block. In the `catch` block put `print(error)`. Your code just ignores any error. These changes will let you see them so you know what to fix.

Comment: `decode(title1.self,…`, this code doesn’t make much sense and shouldn’t compile as far as I can see. Make sure you post the code you are actually using when you experience the issue.